# Font Face isn't working in IIS 8.0

Tags: css, iis, fonts, woff2

I have a font-face in my program generated from Font Squirrel I just can't get it to work in IIS, it works in localhost. I added **application/font-woff** [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594823/mime-type-for-woff-fonts) to my MIME Types but it still doesn't want to work.

```
Context
--Fonts
----font location
--css files
```

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'wallStreetFont';
    src: url('Fonts/subway-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Fonts/subway-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Fonts/subway-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('Fonts/subway-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Fonts/subway-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**EDIT CURRENT MIME**

I am using the default IIS 8 MIME **font/x-woff**

Comment: How are you calling it in? Did you try the sample output in the Font Squirrel zip?

Comment: If you are using IIS 8 you shouldn't have to add a mime type in your web config for WOFF.  In fact it would more likely error for having a duplicate.

Comment: @Aibrean yes the sample output works

Comment: @ColinBacon I read that after I posted. So I currenly have font/x-woff , this is inherited from IIS 8.0 . But still no luck on getting the correct font

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Great to see WOFF2 being included in Font Squirrel fonts!  Whilst IIS 8 does not need a mime type added for `WOFF` it will need one for `WOFF2`.  The W3C [recommends](http://dev.w3.org/webfonts/WOFF2/spec/#IMT):

```
application/font-woff2
```

For more info on `WOFF2` see [here](https://gist.github.com/sergejmueller/cf6b4f2133bcb3e2f64a).

To add the mime type in IIS, modify your `Web.Config` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- ... -->
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- ... -->
    <staticContent>
      <!-- ... -->
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
    <!-- ... -->
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I added `woff2` but still nothing

Comment: If you look in your dev tools. Are you getting a 404 when it tries to get the font file?  Is so check the path is correct and that you have permissions to browse to it in your browser.

Comment: Yes it does, `http://192.168.72.196:85/bundles/Fonts/subway-webfont.woff2` I'm not sure where they are getting the bundles folder from though. Any idea?

Comment: I assume you are using ASP.NET bundling and minification.  If you set this in your bundle config `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true`.  Your local host should behave the same as on your production server.

Comment: Thanks for all the help it is now working. It was a combination of the `woff2` and the 404 error, which ended up being a misspelling in my bundle. Thank you!

Comment: This didn't help me. I have the `.woff` and `.woff2` files in the same folder. I can get the `.woff` but not the `.woff2`. I tried adding this code and also added the `Mime Type` manually using `IIS` but still I get `404` error. What can I try again?

Comment: @SollyM as patronising as this is going to sound, check your Dev Tools to see what address it's trying to pull, and follow the path to see if it's aiming where you think it is. Check spelling etc. too
EDIT: Also clear your cache as per Varun's solution if you still get the issue (CTRL+Shift+R Win and Cmd+Shift+R Mac)

Comment: FOUND IT : If you are still getting a 404, check if you edited the right Web.config ... I was working in the wrong one, it must be the root Web.config

Answer (score 82):

In order to make woff and woff2 fonts to properly work in IIS you should add the following MIME types to the Web.Config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>  
  <system.webServer>    
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
        <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
```

If you still face the 404 error on Google Chrome you should clear your browser cache before reloading the page.

Comment: The spec is now recommending mimeType for woff to be [application/font-woff](http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b).

Comment: I was only getting a .woff2 404 issue and this worked for me.  I only used the lines pertaining to woff2

Answer (score 28):

Note that it is also possible to configure MIME types within IIS Manager. Just select the website and then double click on the MIME Types icon under IIS in the main pane.

[image]

You should then see a list of all of the existing MIME Types and be able to add new ones using the Add... link in the right pane.

Comment: why not use web.config,?!!

Comment: @MojtabaPourmirzaei Because not everybody is a sysadmin. That is the whole reason IIS has UI.

Comment: If you're deploying a non-.NET website in IIS, you need to do it this way (e.g. an Angular app).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue today while deploying a Web solution Metro4 UI icons and switching from the CDN to the Compiled option.

My project was developed using WebSharper platform, but the solution is anyway independent from these implementation details.

Long story short, I've discover that I had to add the file extension, e.g. for `.ttf`, inside the `security` section under the `system.webServer` of the `Web.config`.

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions>
            <add fileExtension=".ttf" allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

The same configuration option is also available under the GUI settings of IIS

[image: IIS GUI]

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the following:

1. bundling in MVC5
2. building bootstrap
3. using @font-face in bootstrap

I had a min.css file deployed on the server, that non-min file was included in the bundle. Once I deleted the .min.css file. It all worked.