# application/font-woff2 not working when using Asp.Net VNext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, woff2

I'm doing some experiments with VNext + OSX + Chrome. I'm trying to get a woff2 file

```
GET http://localhost:5003/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0
```

But an error occur. See the request's header below

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:5003
Request URL:http://localhost:5003/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

This is my Startup.cs

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        });

        // Add MVC to the request pipeline
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
```

I saw inside AspNet project at Github about StaticFiles (Link bellow) and it seems to be supported.

https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles/FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.cs

Can you guys give me some help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Font Face isn't working in IIS 8.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796609/font-face-isnt-working-in-iis-8-0)

Comment: @CharlesBurns actually, my post isn't about II8 specifically and the other solution won't work because I'm not working with Web.Config. They are not the same solution. Not even the same question.

Comment: Both accepted answers mention the same edit Web.Config and both refer to adding a MIME type to prevent a 404 error. The other question mentions IIS8 in title only, not tags. It does look like both involved *two* problems: MIME types for both, pre-release software in one, a typo in the other. I'll remove my close vote.

Comment: This question and answer also applies to v=4.3.0. It solves the issues i had in my project. Thanks

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The file format `woff2` is in the [mapping list](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/5c8ae98e5bebe7b367fdae2a98082285db98ff3b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.cs) but this was added recently (February 2015) so  you may not use a release that contains this change. So to add a custom file format you can use the IIS way using `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Or using `StaticFilesOptions`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    StaticFileOptions options = new StaticFileOptions();
    FileExtensionContentTypeProvider typeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
    if (!typeProvider.Mappings.ContainsKey(".woff2"))
    {
        typeProvider.Mappings.Add(".woff2", "application/font-woff2");
    }
    options.ContentTypeProvider = typeProvider;
    app.UseStaticFiles(options);
}
```

Comment: You were right, the problem was because I was using an alpha  release before this changes. Thanks.

Comment: The mime type in your Web.config code needs to be application/font-woff2. The "2" is missing.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it.

Comment: The link for the mapping list does not work anymore, this is the [correct one](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.cs).

Comment: Thanks for this useful tip. Worked on my project.

Comment: The current standard mime type is `font/woff2`, see  https://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF2/#IMT or the linked mapping list

Comment: Thank you very much this save a lots & lots of time.

Answer (score 16):

add a mime type declaration to your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

for more info see:

[Set mime types for web fonts in IIS](http://codingstill.com/2013/01/set-mime-types-for-web-fonts-in-iis/)

[Quick fix: IIS .woff font file 404 not found in asp.net mvc](http://ideasof.andersaberg.com/development/quick-fix-iis-woff-font-file-404-not-found-in-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: In case someone else has issues, try removing the . in .woff2, that fixed it for me after I added the above mimeMap to my web.config.

Answer (score 2):

If above did not work for you (didn't work for me). Then try with this one :

```
<mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
```

Comment: Worked for me as well.  I guess the entry that they built in includes the . in the fileExtension because when I add the map with .woff2 as the extension I get an error that there is a duplicate entry.  When I removed the . it started working.  Great find!

Answer (score 0):

add mime type in plesk

```
application/font-woff2  .woff2
```

it worked for me

Comment: Can you explain a bit?

Comment: Open Web Server settings in plesk hosting panel  there u can find the option MIME types . Just add that mime type there .

Answer (score 0):

I needed to enable the extension first (which could be done in IIS too) like:

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <fileExtensions>
        <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
        <add fileExtension=".woff2" allowed="true" />
      </fileExtensions>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
...
</system.webServer>
```

as well as adding the previously mentioned static content...

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
  </staticContent>
  ...
</system.webServer>
```