# IIS 7 and font awesome .woff 404 error

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, iis, font-face, font-awesome

I'm getting a 404 error when trying to load `.woff`, `.woff2`, and `.ttf` files in my MVC 5 application. Following the guidance of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312063/font-awesome-error-404-on-fonts) in which I have the same error, nothing seems to be working for me. Below is the following is what I currently have:

In my web config file

```
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/x-woff2" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="font/x-ttf" />
    </staticContent> 
  </system.webServer>
```

In IIS, I did the following steps:

1. Under connections, select MIME Types
2. Right Click and select "Add..."
3. For each file type, File name extension: `.woff` MIME type: `font/x-woff`

The error happens in both IE 11 and Chrome. Please help on how I can correct this.

Comment: Firefox loads them properly?

Comment: I knoe you're using IIS7 but have you tried these suggestions? Seems like using application/font-woff2 instead of font/x-woff2 might work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796609/font-face-isnt-working-in-iis-8-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing more research, the reason it was not loading properly was because of Bundling. In have the following in my files:

In my BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/font-awesome/css").Include("~/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

In my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
@Styles.Render("~/font-awesome/css")
```

I removed the two pieces of code above and added font awesome file directly the _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<link href="~/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```