# Why does Firefox re-request fonts when the page is resized?

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-face

I have a fairly simple Bootstrap3 site with a few custom fonts embedded in the CSS with `@font-face` rules. It works great. The pages are being generated by Django so when I'm testing it I can also see the local requests the browser makes.

When I resize the browser window, I see hundreds of font requests:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2014 13:42:59] "GET /static/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro_400italic.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2014 13:42:59] "GET /static/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro_400.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2014 13:42:59] "GET /static/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro_700.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2014 13:42:59] "GET /static/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro_400italic.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2014 13:42:59] "GET /static/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro_400.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2014 13:42:59] "GET /static/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro_700.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2014 13:42:59] "GET /static/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro_400italic.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2014 13:42:59] "GET /static/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro_400.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2014 13:42:59] "GET /static/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro_700.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2014 13:42:59] "GET /static/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro_400italic.woff HTTP/1.1"
```

All for the same custom fonts. Over and over and over again until I stop resizing.

I realise that most people don't resize their browser that often but why is Firefox doing this? Can I stop it?

Chrome does not exhibit this behaviour.

Here's how the file looks with `curl`. It seems to have the right Content-Type and there's no weird super-uncaching things in there.

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Last-Modified: Sun, 30 Nov 2014 22:53:43 GMT
Content-Length: 65452
Content-Type: application/x-font-woff
Server: Werkzeug/0.9.4 Python/2.7.4
Date: Thu, 04 Dec 2014 14:13:57 GMT
```

Comment: give us example page to test, i notice similar problem that exists only on some browsers with some plugins (was fixed after next browser version), maybe its only in your browser or only with some plugins.

Comment: I second ViliusL. I have a site that has font-face rules but does not exhibit this behavior in Firefox

Comment: What are your `font-face` rules?  Are they inside media queries?

Comment: I tried both `firebug` and `wireshark`. My firefox does not exhibit this behaviour. Give us a page to test. May be something else is sending those requests. Even if multiple requests are sent you can send [304 not modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) with proper `.htaccess` settings

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same font reloading issue in Firefox on every browser window resize. Turns out it had to do with specifying `local()` fonts which weren't installed locally, before specifying `url()` fonts.

If I use the following css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url("../fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff2") format('woff2'), url("../fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

the behaviour shows up in Firefox if I haven't got `Roboto-Regular` installed locally, if I then install `Roboto-Regular` locally, the problem goes away. Since I'm not expecting everyone to have `Roboto-Regular` installed locally, I removed the `local()` font references from the `@font-face`'s `src` tag.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff2") format('woff2'), url("../fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

That fixes it for me. No more unwanted font reloading on every browser window resize.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me too. I think this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a stab at this, but with FF comes a ton of customization (esp if you're running addons).

1. Are you running any page CSS overrides via a plugin/addon via the local browser
2. Is there a version update available for your FF install?
3. Does the issue appear on in SBX/testing or does it also appear "in the wild" on another computer?  When browser testing, I prefer to test on multiple machines (and device types) to isolate local configuration issues.
4. Have you run through any litmus/page render tests?

Comment: Welcome to the site - there is no need to end your questions and answers with a signature as it only serves to detract from the content proper. It's fine to have it in your user bio though.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, didn't realize!  - Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Others have suggested this for FF:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm hosting everything on the same domain.

Comment: Ah ok, not that then!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox uses a different render engine (Gecko) compared to Chrome (Blink), which could explain the different render behavior. However as there is no explicit information or documentation to be found on this subject, no concrete answer can be given. Best is to take this up to Mozilla and in the meantime see if you can use an alternative to @font-face if it is hampering your work.

Answer (score 0):

Some fonts do not work very well at certain sizes so when you increase or decrease the font size what Firefox will do is change the font to something very similar. You can test this out by going through all the fonts and changing font size slowly. Some of the fonts are so close to each other you may not even notice a difference though so watch carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The blog post [Woff and Caching](http://www.lubyte.de/en/blog/2010/08/10/woff-caching-firefox)* suggest that when using a wrong/unknown MIME type, the font won't be cached and requested again every time it is needed. In the article they don't use the correct type though, as it hasn't been standardized back then.

The article is rather old, from 2010 and might not be relevant any more but using the correct MIME type certainly won't hurt. The [correct MIME type for WOFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594823/mime-type-for-woff-fonts) is `application/font-woff`.

<sub>* Originally posted by [Bes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4435245/bes) but deleted by a ♦. While not explaining why the font has to be requested again on resizing, I think it could still be helpful to consider caching issues.</sub>