# Webfont Not Working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, font-face

So, I'm trying to import the StateFace font into a web app I'm working on. I'm using the following css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'StateFace Regular';
  src: url('../fonts/StateFace-Regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/StateFace-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/StateFace-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/StateFace-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/StateFace-Regular-webfont.svg#statefaceregular') format('svg');
}
.state {
  font-family: 'StateFace Regular';
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.state.state-ak:before {
  content: 'A';
}
.state.state-al:before {
  content: 'B';
}
.state.state-ar:before {
  content: 'C';
}
.state.state-az:before {
  content: 'D';
}
.state.state-ca:before {
  content: 'E';
}
.state.state-co:before {
  content: 'F';
}
.state.state-ct:before {
  content: 'G';
}
.state.state-de:before {
  content: 'H';
}
.state.state-fl:before {
  content: 'I';
}
.state.state-ga:before {
  content: 'J';
}
.state.state-hi:before {
  content: 'K';
}
.state.state-ia:before {
  content: 'L';
}
.state.state-il:before {
  content: 'N';
}
.state.state-ks:before {
  content: 'P';
}
.state.state-ky:before {
  content: 'Q';
}
.state.state-la:before {
  content: 'R';
}
.state.state-ma:before {
  content: 'S';
}
.state.state-me:before {
  content: 'U';
}
.state.state-mi:before {
  content: 'V';
}
.state.state-mn:before {
  content: 'W';
}
.state.state-mo:before {
  content: 'X';
}
.state.state-ms:before {
  content: 'Y';
}
.state.state-mt:before {
  content: 'Z';
}
.state.state-nc:before {
  content: 'a';
}
.state.state-nd:before {
  content: 'b';
}
.state.state-ne:before {
  content: 'c';
}
.state.state-nh:before {
  content: 'd';
}
.state.state-nj:before {
  content: 'e';
}
.state.state-nm:before {
  content: 'f';
}
.state.state-nv:before {
  content: 'g';
}
.state.state-ny:before {
  content: 'h';
}
.state.state-oh:before {
  content: 'i';
}
.state.state-ok:before {
  content: 'j';
}
.state.state-or:before {
  content: 'k';
}
.state.state-pa:before {
  content: 'l';
}
.state.state-ri:before {
  content: 'm';
}
.state.state-sc:before {
  content: 'n';
}
.state.state-sd:before {
  content: 'o';
}
.state.state-tn:before {
  content: 'p';
}
.state.state-tx:before {
  content: 'q';
}
.state.state-ut:before {
  content: 'r';
}
.state.state-va:before {
  content: 's';
}
.state.state-vt:before {
  content: 't';
}
.state.state-wa:before {
  content: 'u';
}
.state.state-wi:before {
  content: 'v';
}
.state.state-wv:before {
  content: 'w';
}
.state.state-wy:before {
  content: 'x';
}
```

It works fine in IE (9-11), but not in Firefox or Chrome. I've looked, and both browsers are pulling in the font file with 200 (or 304) responses with a content length > 0, but the content is not displaying in the font. The Glyphicons font that comes with Bootstrap is working fine, however, and the StateFace font works on other pages, so it must be something specific to my implementation. Does anything stand out as being off?

Edit: The css files are in ~/Content, and the font files are in ~/fonts

Comment: Can you edit your post with your directory structure and file locations?

Comment: @CarsonCrane I'm compiling this along side the Bootstrap less, using the same directory location as the Glyphicons webfonts, and the StateFace files are in the same directory as the Glyphicons files. That combined with the 200/304 responses seems to indicate that it's pointing to the correct location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the font on fontsquirrel which is where I assume you downloaded it.

Fontsquirrel's own demo file doesn't work for me in Chrome, and their TTF format doesn't work in windows:

[image: Font not working]
[image: Demo not working]

I would try to find a mirror for the file somewhere else and use that, or maybe its just straight up broken and you might have to find another option.

Comment: I was wondering if it was the font itself. Wanted to make sure there's not something I'm doing incorrectly somehow before discounting it. Still, not sure why IE is working, since it appears to be pulling in the woff...

Comment: The files from the github repo work properly in Chrome and Firefox, so I'm going to mark this as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the woff source call in your CSS. You must add the woff source to get chrome support. Read this answer on [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594823/mime-type-for-woff-fonts). I reccommend using [Font Squirrel Web Font Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). Just upload your font and it generates all the CSS you need for cross browser capabilities.

**Update**:

Another problem that it could be is that Bootstrap less could be overriding your styles because your CSS selector is not specific enough.

**Update 2**:

Just downloaded the font from [font squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/stateface) and it seems that it doesn't work in firefox or chrome for me either.

Comment: The woff source is in there. The second src is just really long.

Comment: just some CORS issues. That's just an unrelated issue with ArcGIS, though.

Comment: as far as chrome and firefox are telling me, the correct font is being applied, it just doesn't appear properly. if I turn off the font, it changes to the page's default font.

Comment: in your console look at your `.state` is there a line-through font family? @Ixonal

Comment: I don't think the issue has anything to do with @Ixonal's code. Looks to be a problem with the source files. See my answer.

Comment: Seems like this font is bugged in Chrome and Firefox. Just downloaded it and it's not working for me either. @Ixonal

Comment: yeah, @CarsonCrane I just downloaded it as well. And it didn't work for me either.

Comment: I'm going to pull it from their github repo and see if that's any better.