# How solve flickering Font Awesome Icons?

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome, cdn, webfonts

if I using what is everywhere recommended - using CDN attachment for "[Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)" everytime flickering "on page load".

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Q how prevent flickering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my solution I download font resources to server

- http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css - save in path "css"
- http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot - save in path "fonts"
- http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf - save in path "fonts"
- http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2 - save in path "fonts"
- http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff - save in path "fonts"
- http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg - save in path "fonts"

But even than still happened - Chrome and Firefox too.

For that is there font type "woff2". I add new webserver handler:

for [#iis](http://www.iis.net/) add

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
```

and for [#nginx](http://nginx.org/) add (see how [Mime type for WOFF fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594823/mime-type-for-woff-fonts/17568582#17568582))

```
/etc/nginx/mime.types || or /usr/local/nginx/conf/mime.types
font/woff2 woff2;
```

Mime types by [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types).

Now font icons are loaded fast like images.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: yes, because you can do it on shared hosting. Bad answer. Who cares about locahost

Comment: @Grasper This solution is for one enviroment not all. I strictly build only on systems with full control.

Comment: how is it useful if it's only you who can access it? Unless you have your own servers where you host your web.

Comment: @Grasper if you have something valuable or solution please contribute.

Comment: I bumped into svg instead of using font icons but it flickers too in chrome.

Comment: @Grasper in my investigation this is because browser loading resources from another domain and therefore rendering delayed.

Comment: What are the codes you've added to the nginx and iis?

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar that is definition for #webserver to detect type of file

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to add `@font-face` directly in the `<head>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style name="FontAwesome">
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'FontAwesome';
          src: url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
          src: url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
               url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
               url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
               url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
               url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
          font-weight: normal;
          font-style: normal;
        }
    </style>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css}" rel="stylesheet">
```

This what Google do in Youtube and other websites

Comment: I think it made it faster, But still flickers.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it appeared that I have included the FontAwesome stylesheet twice and after removing one of them the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from using Web Font to SVG.  Cured the problem.

Comment: thx for workaround - I think it may be the same bahaviour - local vs cdn