# How to set up mod expires for fonts

Tags: apache, mod-expires

I'd like to set expiry date for fonts. Following definition isn't working on `apache 2.2.15`.

```
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff       "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2         "access plus 1 month"
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First, add proper MIME types definitions:

```
AddType application/font-sfnt            otf ttf
AddType application/font-woff            woff
AddType application/font-woff2           woff2
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject    eot
```

Next, change your configuration lines to:

```
ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/font-sfnt "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
```

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, mark it as correct :) thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I find it easier to use file extensions rather than mine types, especially as the [Woff mime type changed a few times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594823/mime-type-for-woff-fonts).

```
# Set up caching on font files for 6 months (60 * 60 * 24 * 180 = 15724800)
<filesMatch ".([eE][oO][tT]|[tT][tT][fF]|[sS][vV][gG]|[Ww][Oo][Ff][Ff]|[Ww][Oo][Ff][Ff]2)$">
   ExpiresDefault A15724800
   Header append Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>
```