# html; load custom fonts with base64

Tags: html, css

I can load fonts from server. but it's not proper way. 
How can I load fonts with base 64?
i used this my css file

```
          @font-face {<br>
            font-family: 'MyFontFamily';<br>
            src: url(data:font/ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,data_base64);<br>
        }<br>



    .t{<br>
        font-family: "MyFontFamily";<br>
        background-color: red;<br>
    }
```

this is my html page

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css"> 
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class = 't'>test</p>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Making a massive assumption here, but the line breaks aren't actually in your css, are they?

Comment: _“I can load fonts from server. but it's not proper way”_ – says who? And “proper” in what regard/by what criteria anyway?

Answer (score 6):

If I understood you correctly then you want to include a base64 encoded font inside of your css file.

To do that use the following syntax:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,base64_code_here) format('woff');
}
```

The data header and format change according to the encoded font.

I made an example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b7sp45ca/

Also as Chris J mentioned in the comment section if the line breaks are in your code then you are going to have to get rid of them.

(Resources used: http://sosweetcreative.com/2613/font-face-and-base64-data-uri)

Comment: thanks, this works, i have been looking for special site for this during one hour. http://transfonter.org/. this help me.

Comment: Use `font/woff` instead of `application/x-font-woff` for the mime type. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5142316/8583692).