# Time picker on "Date and Time" not showing

Tags: 2sxc

1. The Time picker for "*default (date/time picker)*" on a *date and time* field is missing - although set to be shown. Manually appending time, causes the field to be marked as invalid.
   Any reason why, how to fix it or What is missing (DLL / JS / CSS ...)?
   (**shown with red ellipse on the attachment**)

<s>2. Why the UI showing some Chinese (I think) characters?

           (**shown with blue ellipses on the attachment**)




    3. The "**Close**" icon and the "**Save**" / "**Not save**" button icons are not showing.

        Stared in one of the *last updates* I've done to the 2sxc add-in (I think it was in one of the versions

        following v08.05.01)...

        (... *I'm guessing that [2] and [3] are related* ...)

        (**shown with green ellipses on the attachment**)</s>

[Configuration and Saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68S8Q.png)

Answer (score 1):

### For (2) and (3), I've found a way around.

... and - as I've guessed - was pretty straightforward...

If any one comes across this situation, I've currently found solution from [@JeremyWeir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45767/jeremyweir) in his *[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29016670/6714258)*:

Add this to the **web.config** in **DNN**'s *root* directory (e.g. "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\[**DNN**]\web.config"):

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <!--
                 remove first in case they are defined in IIS already,
                 which would cause a runtime error
            -->
            <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've also added ***eot***, ***otf***, ***svg*** and ***ttf*** same way as suggested *[in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20723357/6714258)* by [@Steve Eynon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1532548/steve-eynon)
 .

Answer (score 0):

this is happening for me too. I opened an issue on github
[DateTime picker not showing time pick](https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/990)

You can follow it :)